# What are the specifications/recommendations for data types in JAX-RPC web services?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

When developing a web service using Java, Axis1 and JAX-RPC, what are the constraints, recommendations and specifications that must be followed when sending complex data types over a web service?

```
For example, the method:
public MyComplexClass webServiceOperation() {
  return new MyComplexClass;
}
```

Is there any limitation on the methods, getters, setters, variables, etc for MyComplexClass?

Comment: My recommendation to someone building web services with Axis is not using Axis. ;)

Comment: @gustafc: This is not helpful. You could at least point out why you don't like Axis and what you would recommend instead. Otherwise this is just a flame.

Comment: I would like to support gustafc by telling (in a friendly way) not to use the old jax-rpc stack. It's just too complex. Please base your webservice on the newer jax-ws (jax-rpc 2.0) spec. You can use the axis2 implementation to create your web service. SOAP webservice technology is already complex enough by itself.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check this excellent article

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-tip-jaxwsrpc/

and this

http://www.nesc.ac.uk/talks/ahm2006/621.ppt‎